# React export default throwing invalid element type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

**EDIT: Never mind, I found the problem. I used Nav.link instead of Nav.Link in the navbar component :/. Works fine now.**

I'm trying to learn react and bootstrap and was building a simple app with a navbar, a couple of pages and a login page. I created a seprate file called Navigation.js to define the Navbar component and exported it so that I can use it in App.js. However, I get the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `Navigation`.

The Navigation.js file path src/components/Navigation.js and for App.js, it is src/App.js.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

App.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  
import './App.css';

import Navigation  from './components/Navigation';
import MainLandingPage from './components/pages/AppLandingPage';
import ContactUs from './components/pages/ContactUs';
import AboutUs from './components/pages/AboutUs';
import Login from './components/pages/Login';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';

import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation/>
      <Switch>                
          <Route path='/about' component={AboutUs}/>                 
          <Route path='/contact' component={ContactUs}/>
          <Route path='/login' component={Login}/> 
          <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>  
          <Route path='/' component={MainLandingPage}/>            
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navigation.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Navigation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect fixed='top' expand='sm' bg='dark' variant='dark'>
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav'/>
                    <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
                        <Nav>
                            <Nav.link href='/'>Main</Nav.link>
                            <Nav.link href='/about'>About Us</Nav.link>
                            <Nav.link href='/contact'>Contact Us</Nav.link>
                            <Nav.link href='/login'>Log in</Nav.link>
                            <Nav.link href='/home'>Homepage</Nav.link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
    );
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

I did look up differences between exporting as default and named exports and I think I got that part right in this case. I also tried defining the Navigation component as a function like:

```
function Navigation() {
    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect fixed='top' expand='sm' bg='dark' variant='dark'>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav'/>
                <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
                    <Nav>
                        <Nav.link href='/'>Main</Nav.link>
                        <Nav.link href='/about'>About Us</Nav.link>
                        <Nav.link href='/contact'>Contact Us</Nav.link>
                        <Nav.link href='/login'>Log in</Nav.link>
                        <Nav.link href='/home'>Homepage</Nav.link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

But I get the same result. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Just checkin, I think you have a typo in `Nav.link`. Can you change it to `Nav.Link` and try again?

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. Fixed it and I edited the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this capital L in Link

```
<Nav.Link href='/'>Main</Nav.Link>
```